# Running VLC player with java

Tags: java

I need to open a video in the VLC Player with Java. I have created this program but I don't know how to run a video with this pre-existing code, what should I add in it?

Currently I am using:

```
package vlc.player;
import java.io.*;
public class vlc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
    InterruptedException 
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\"");
        System.out.println("VLC started.");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information to help. Where's the video? What did you try? Is this even related to Java? To me it looks like you fail to understand how VLC should be used.

Comment: VLC (like most other applications) [has a command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

Comment: Sir this is a Java program in which I need to run vlc media player with the help of Java Language so this is the program which i have created and it is working but i want to play a video or audio file with the help of this code that is my question

Comment: Right. And you do that by using VLC's command line, giving it proper arguments like it's described in the link I've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package vlc.player;
import java.io.*;
public class vlc {
public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
String [] s= new String[] 
{"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe","D:\\Video\\3G\\K.MP4"};  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s); 
System.out.println("VLC started."+"prashant.ibmce@gmail.com");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc you can start VLC with an embedded HTTP server: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#The_HTTP_interface

And the send HTTP requests to perform some operations:

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/

If you only want to play a file once, just start it as

```
vlc.exe file://c:\\path\\file.avi
```